# Kafka Offset and Partition identification

Tags: apache-kafka

I had a few questions from Kafka. Please help me in understanding the problem.
As per [official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_topics), each partition will have one unique sequential id which called offset.

1. How does the offset numbers will be generated i.e based on the message arrival into a partition or offset numbers will be generated whenever the partitions are created?
2. do the same offset ID/number generates/exists in another partition because each partition is independent each other?
3. If the same offset can be possible in another partition then, How consumer uniquely identifies the message across multiple partitions?
4. How does consumer know the particular offset belongs to a particular partition? Please let me understand in both situations like a message with key & without a key?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Each partition maintains the messages it has received in a sequential order where they are identified by an offset. This offset is a sequential number and it automatically generated and assigned to messages.

---

2. Yes this is correct. Message ordering is guaranteed only on the partition level. This means that if you have a topic with multiple partitions, messages on different partitions might have the same offset. Therefore, an offset has a true meaning only within a single partition (as you can also see in the picture below, which is taken from [Kafka Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_topics)).

   [image]

---

3/4. The consumers are subscribed to topics, but behind the scenes they are subscribed to particular partitions (well, if you have a single consumer in the consumer group it will subscribe to all of the partitions). Therefore, when the consumer reads messages from a particular partition, it can uniquely identify messages using their unique offsets which are maintained throughout the partition. As I already mentioned, the message order is guaranteed only within a single partition.

Note that messages without key, will be evenly distributed across the partitions of the topic, in a round-robin fashion. On the other hand, messages with the same key will be stored in the same partition and hence, you can use the key to store and order messages having the same key. For example, if you need to process users and you'd like order guarantee for each distinct user, you can use `userID` as a key, so that all the events of that user are stored in the same partition. Later on, you will be able to consume these user-specific messages, in the order they were originally received.

Comment: Thanks for the replay